# Make a block element stay on the right of a short element

Tags: html, css

I have a little form with checkboxes, where each checkbox is on the left of its description text.

If the description text wraps, I want the next line to stay to the right of the checkbox, and I *don't* want the whole description container itself to be repositioned below the checkbox.

**I don't want this:**

[image]

**And I don't want this:**

[image]

**I want THIS! (forgive my weak image editing skills):**

[image]

I've tried a dozen permutations of `display`/`float` combinations, and I just can't get it.

Below is my source, and [here is my JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8vs21brj/3/)

```
div.outer {
    border: 1px green solid;
    width: 100px;
}

span.check {
    border: 1px orange solid;
}

span.desc {
    border: 1px cyan solid;
}

<div class="outer">
    <span class="check">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>
    <span class="desc">Futures</span>
    <br/>

    <span class="check">
        <input type="checkbox"/>
    </span>
    <span class="desc">I don't currently trade</span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

[Again, here's that JSFiddle link.](http://jsfiddle.net/8vs21brj/3/)

Can someone clue me in?  I'm stumped.  Seems like this shouldn't be so tough.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/8vs21brj/3/)

Comment: note: fixed an accidental html code error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can come up with is to give a fixed width to the `desc` class, and then also add `vertical-align: top`.  The width keeps the `desc` from being wide enough to cause a word wrap.

```
span.desc {
    border: 1px cyan solid;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 90px;              // added
    vertical-align: top;      // added
}
```

I don't like adding fixed widths, but I can't come up with anything better for now.  I'm still open to better answers.

[(See JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/cayotzb8/)

Comment: almost there ...I also tried something just check my answer

Comment: Accepted my own answer, but will gladly accept a different answer if someone comes up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the label relative, you can move the input via position absolute. The span is not needed, but a bit easier if you want to do something with the text:

```
.check{
    position: relative;
}
.check>input{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -25px;
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: How would I apply this to my code?  Unfortunately, I can't change my code too radically at the moment.

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`display: inline-block`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7v07b5L/), which sort of addresses your problem.

Other than that, my advice is to look into fixing the width of the checkbox (or the span containing it).

Comment: No, you didn't solve it, you just made the outer box wider so the wrap wouldn't happen.  (I actually tried many variations of `display: inline-block` before posting.)

Comment: How would fixing the width of the checkbox do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/cayotzb8/4/)

```
div.outer {
  border: 1px green solid;
width: 90px;
}

span.check {
    border: 1px orange solid;
}

span.desc {
  border: 1px cyan solid;
display: inline-block;
width: 60px;
vertical-align: top;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: does this solves the problem ... i am also new to css but just learning and trying to solve your problem

Comment: That's pretty much the same as my answer, isn't it?

Comment: `text-align: left` doesn't do anything.  You're answer is the same as mine.